# interpreting ajax code

Tags: ajax

I have traced some ajax stuff and I am trying to figure out what it means. I was hoping to translate it into a url but it seems to involve some Get request based on searched I did.

An help appreciated.

```
**new Ajax.Request(fspring.baseURL+"search/getProfileResults",
  {parameters:{ajax:1,q:_4,page:_5},onStatOK:function(_6){    var _7=new Element("div");
```

I thought it would be the baseURL in this case

http://helloworld.com/search/getProfileResults  and I know it needs two parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fspring.baseURL` could be anything, so I can't really help you there.  It doesn't ring a bell to me for any particular Javascript library.

The `parameters` object will be converted by [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/options) into a querystring, in this case it'll look something like this:

```
http://helloworld.com/search/getProfileResults?ajax=1&q=_4&page=_5
```

Except `_4` and `_5` will be replaced with the variable contents.

An easier way to figure out what's going on would be to just open up the page in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and look in the Console to see what the AJAX query was.

Comment: thanks for the response. The query when pasted in url box does not deliver results since it sends the request to the server and requires an authorized account. I have API access but limited to 1000 returns and when I use the GUI option available on the site, the results returned are huge. Now you cannot parse it from the html normally but u see it when using firebug. Just wanted to know if there was a way to automate this so i dont have to cut and paste from firebug.